# appropriate method for over dispersion of zeros, but not count data (0/1 did you move; 0/1 did you move to x town)

Tags: regression, zero-inflation

I am looking at a migration outcome question. Basically, it's did you move (0/1); and if you did move, did you move to x town (0/1), as a function of tenure, economic conditions, etc.. I am somewhat familiar with ZINB and ZIP models, but my understanding is that they are for count data (the example I've seen is with fishing: 0/1 for did you go fishing, and a count variable for how many fish were caught). Is it also appropriate for a 0/1 outcome, or should I specify a different model?